# Why CRONTAB tasks are lost when quit Putty session?

Tags: cron, solaris

I logged to remote computer, running under Solaris, using Putty and added some jobs to be run by *cron*. When I quit console and logged once again all jobs was lost.

```
crontab -l myuser
```

How do I persist jobs to be run even after I quit console?

Comment: Please be more precise about what you did. Is this correct: You ran `crontab -l myuser`, logged out, logged in again, ran `crontab -l myuser` again and the outputs were different?

Comment: Jobs are persistent. There's something that you aren't telling us that is crucial in answering your question, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

ALWAYS use `crontab -e` to edit your cronjobs. And remember to save and quit when exiting your editor. When the editor quits, it will tell you if there is an error preventing it being moved to the active set of cronjobs.

If you are using `crontab -e`, you are not correctly exiting you editor to make your changes persist.

To exit the editor, do not close the putty screen.

If your editor is VIM or VI the keys needed to exit are `ESC :wq`

If your editor is EMACS the keys needed to exit are `Ctrl+x Ctrl+c`

If your editor is Nano the keys needed to exit are `Ctrl+x y Enter`

After you exit your editor you should either see an error or `crontab: installing new crontab`. IF you see the latter, you can type `crontab -l` and you should see your cron jobs. This will persist upon exit.

If you see an error, then fix the error and try again.